# Getting an object not found error while plotting a graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a function that takes a data frame, an x-axis variable, and a y-axis variable to create a visual.
Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
create_visual <-
  function(data, x_axis, y_axis) {
    ggplot(data = data) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x_axis, y = y_axis))
  }
```

When I run this code:

```
create_visual(penguins,flipper_length_mm,body_mass_g)
```

I get this error: `'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'flipper_length_mm' not found'`

I have loaded the dataset `Palmerpenguins` and checked the `penguins` data table, and it does have `flipper_length_mm`, yet I am getting this error. Could you please help me figure out where I am making a mistake?

Comment: If the length and mass data are in `penguins` and not stand along objects, you need to do `create_visual(penguins, penguins$flipper_length_mm, penguins$body_mass_g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the function attributes as strings, it are not objects you will provide. This would cause the error. However within your function you have to use `get` on those strings to get it working. Below a small demo including the use in the graph's title and axis legends.

```
set.seed(123)

penguins <- data.frame(
  flipper_length_mm = sample(120L:300L, 10L),
  body_mass_g = sample(2200L:4500L, 10L)
)

library(ggplot2)

create_visual <- function(data, x_axis, y_axis) {

    ggplot(data = get(data)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = get(x_axis), y = get(y_axis))) +
    labs(title = paste("Relation between", x_axis, "and", y_axis), x = x_axis, y = y_axis)

}

create_visual("penguins", "flipper_length_mm", "body_mass_g")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using aes() ggplot assumes you are giving it the column names you want to plot (so it thinks your column name is "x_axis" without trying to read its value). To use parameters I would use aes_() instead. example:

```
create_visual <- function(data,x_axis,y_axis){
   x_axis <- as.name(x_axis)
   y_axis <- as.name(y_axis)
   ggplot(data=data) + geom_point(mapping=aes_(x=x_axis,y=y_axis))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
attach(penguins)
```

and then run your code!

Comment: Using `attach` is generally a bad idea, especially given that the tidyverse developers have a whole subset of their packages (all of the tidyeval protocols) dedicated to *not* doing this

Comment: Whatever, it works!

Comment: Until you need to do it again, which is the purpose of a function. If you're going to recommend an anti-pattern, at least including the downsides of it and the steps necessary to undo the anti-pattern (calling `detach` after each time you call this function) would be helpful. Otherwise you're just introducing different bugs a couple lines later